# What is the correct way to mount a rails app and sinatra apps in a parent rackup application?

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler, rack, unicorn

I have a parent rack application with a config.ru and Gemfile, and within app/ am trying to mount several rails and sinatra applications. Each of the mounted applications have their own Gemfile (so they can be developed against independently) and own databases (rake tasks are available from the root of each mounted application). I am then trying to run a single unicorn master process from the parent root, that reads the parent config.ru, which loads in each of the mounted applications.

I am using rvm and bundler. Each mounted application as well as the parent application has `bundle install` install the gems into the same gemset.

So, the problem I have is when I run `bundle exec unicorn -c app/unicorn.conf -E development` from the root of the parent rack app, I get errors about some gem required in a mounted application's Gemfile not being available to the parent's Gemfile. (for example, cannot load rails).

From what I have read and guess I'm experiencing, bundler will load only one Gemfile (in this case, the one at the parent app's root). I've seen hacks that eval other Gemfiles in lower down directories when I `bundle install`, but this often breaks when there are the same gems across Gemfiles all being dynamically written to the parent's Gemfile.

When I try run unicorn without `bundle exec`, this appears to work on one machine but not on others. I'm guessing that this is because gem binaries are not locked to those listed in a specific Gemfile. I wonder if it only loads gems in the current rvm environment, and thus make available all gems for a specific gemset (in which case this would be the ideal), or maybe it makes available other gems that are available globally. Any clarification on this would be helpful.

My question is, if I want to start unicorn from the parent rack app, do I have to list all gems used in mounted applications' Gemfiles, in the parent rack app Gemfile? Or should I be doing some sort of extra configuration around `bundler/setup ; Bundler.require(:default)` in each of the mounted applications' config.ru/application.rb files, such as assigning a new Gemfile (`ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)`)?

The first approach just seems a right pain, cos' i'd have to change 2 Gemfiles at any one time. But I can't get the 2nd approach to work.

Or is there something fundamental about developing multiple rack applications independently and trying to mount them all in a single rackup that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

for separate `Gemfile`s you need to clean the environment first:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
  require 'bundler/setup'
  Bundler.require(:default)
end
```

You might also need to unload previously loaded gems to prevent using wrong gem versions using my [gem `bundler-unload`](https://github.com/mpapis/bundler-unload), for example see https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler/blob/master/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb.